# c# bitmap into picturebox

Tags: c#, bitmap, using

`

```
    public Bitmap catchFullScreen()
    { Bitmap r = new Bitmap(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width ,SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height);
        Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle (0,0,SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width ,SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height);
        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width ,SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
                r = bitmap;
                pictureBox1.Image = r;
                pictureBox1.Update();
                pictureBox1.Refresh();
            }
            pictureBox2.Image = r; // breakpoint 1 
            pictureBox2.Update();  // breakpoint 2
            pictureBox2.Refresh();
        }
        pictureBox3.Image = r;
        pictureBox3.Update();
        pictureBox3.Refresh();
        return r;
    }
```

`
Here is my capture screenshot, but something strange is going on, picturebox1 and 2 is able to capture , but picturebox3 does not.
 further more, breakpoint1 works but breakpoint2 never arrives,

Why cant i use this bitmap after i am outside the using routines??
more important it wont return r?
suggestions please!

Comment: You are disposing the bitmap with that using statement.  Since you want to continue using it beyond this routine, you shouldn't dispose of it.

Answer (score 3):

Bitmap is a class, that is a reference type. When you dispose `bitmap` you also dispose your `r`. If you want to continue using `r` while disposing `bitmap`, consider using something like [Bitmap.Clone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.clone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).